# Different HTTP responses using same packages in two different py virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, virtualenv

I created two virtual enviroments in the same VM.

`pip freeze` and `pip list` show the same installed packages.

The output from [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) Lib is different.

How can I see what makes them different? Should I provide some code?

- requests=2.13 with security
- urllib=1.20
- python 3.4.5

Comment: please do. And provide the `pip freeze` output of both venvs also.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure the page you're accessing is supposed to return the same content every time? [Some pages change with every request.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111425/average-length-of-google/)

If you really should be getting identical responses, check that the requests you're sending are actually the same. You can do this using [requests_toolbelt](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumputils.html):

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.utils import dump

response = requests.post('http://google.com/', data={'foo': 'bar'})
data = dump.dump_all(response)
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

This will dump each pair of request and response in the redirect history. The request generated by the code above looks like this:

```
< POST / HTTP/1.1
< Host: google.com
< Connection: keep-alive
< Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
< Accept: */*
< User-Agent: python-requests/2.13.0
< Content-Length: 7
< Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
< 
< foo=bar
```

Make sure the URLs, all the headers, and the request bodies match exactly.